# iOS icon not updating when changing it in xcode 5.1

Tags: ios, xcode, icons

I am changing an icon via the app build settings; I tried using the appicon xcassets folder but that did not work.

I changed the build settings to manually input my images; put them all in as png with the correct naming schema; still no go.

Tried restarting xcode; cleaning xcode project; rebooting the devices, reinstalling the application from scratch... nothing.

Is this a known bug within xcode 5.1?

Edit:

I've even recreated the project and rebooted my macintosh. Everytime I create it; it just stays as the blank white generic icon.

Edit 2:

Xcode wasn't the fault; refer to my solution below.

Comment: Is it the correct size?

Comment: yes, all icons are correct sizes for their respective ios versions.

Comment: even added the icons names to the plist file

Comment: Xcode has a tendency to not update assets all the way. Try deleting the app and reinstalling.

Comment: What do you mean by this `"cleaning xcode"`? Was it dirty or something, not sure what this means.

Comment: @Popeye problem is solved; and I mean cleaning the project files and rebuilding.

Answer (score 3):

Trivially, did you tried to performa a clean in the project ? `cmd + shift + K`

Comment: yes I stated in my problem that I did; thanks though ;)

Answer (score 1):

Once I had problems because my image was too high resolution and it did not take it.  The way I figured it out was to select an image from the film like icon; I selected a standard icon and then I realised it must be some characteristic of the icon making the system ignore it.

Look at your original and new icons in an image processing tool.  How do they differ in size image size, dimensions, color depth, naming?  Try loading each one up in your image processing tool to see if you get any complaints.  Cross-reference with the requirements at

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconMatrix.html

Comment: I Tried checking against a working icon; all parameters match up exactly.

Comment: These include: Dinension, scale settings, resampling settings, resolution. However the resulting size is nearly double in the later (I just think that is a result of the colors used.) Both files are png.

Comment: I tried uploading to icon strike (an icon testing site); and it does not show up there as well

Comment: There is something funny about the icon on its own because two tools (Xcode and icon strike) don't like it.  I recommend trying a low-level tool.  E.g. pngcrush (say -n -v options).  I have darwin ports, so can install it via sudo port install pngcrush.  It will give lots of data on the png file.

Comment: "solved" above, thanks for your time @Faisal Memon :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why this is the solution but it is:

My graphic designer sent me a .tif file format; when I converted it to a png it broke the image file.

When I asked my graphic designer for a straight .png right out of photoshop it worked fine.

I have no idea why this is the case; but it worked.